# I am trying to color code the plot circles in my scatter plot and reference to the legend. The data is via a csv file

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

[Sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lAxE.png) I want to color code the circle plots in my scatter and associate them with a legend.

I have made various attempts at a solution referencing matplotlib.org and this website.  All to no avail.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

hysector = pd.read_csv('LF98TRUU_Lvl3_sector.csv',index_col=0)
hysector.plot.scatter(x='OAD',y='OAS',s=hysector['Wgt']*35,label='Sector');
```

Comment: [This](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_demo2.html) and [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html) would be the relevant examples from the matplotlib documentation. (But note that you are using pandas to plot here.)

Comment: Please include the sample data.

Comment: show code which you try to use ? And add some data. Create mininal working coe  so we could copy code and run it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help editing/improving my post (my 1st).  The data is contained in a CSV file (that I was hoping I could upload here but I do not see that option).  The format of the CSV is 4 columns: [category as index], Wgt, OAD, OAS.  the categories are Communications, consumer, Energy, Capital Goods, Technology and number values are assigned to column.

Comment: Found a solution.... had 10 elements that i wanted to assign a color for.... so I just made a list and did it manually.  Not the most efficient solution, but simple and got the job done.  ---  color = ['green','red','black','purple','orange','brown','yellow','grey','aqua','blue']

Comment: hysector.plot.scatter(x='OAD',y='OAS',s=hysector['Wgt']*35,color = ['green','red','black','purple','orange','brown','yellow','grey','aqua','blue'])